# How to replace columns in a mutate_at with another variable from the tibble itself?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to replace multiple columns in `mtcars` with a variable from `mtcars` itself.

For instance, this is the code for replacing using a scalar:

```
mutate_at(.tbl = mtcars, vars(mpg, carb), function(x) 1)
```

Now, I would like to be able to pass for instance `disp` to replace the values in `mpg` and `carb`

I tried:

```
mutate_at(.tbl = mtcars, vars(mpg, carb), funs(function(x = .tbl) x[['disp']]))
```

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :    Column `mpg` is of unsupported
>   type function

But I would rather prefer a solution that allows passing unquoted names. For instance, can I coerce `funs()` to look only into the environment that is being mutated?

Comment: plain and simple : `mtcars %>% mutate(mpg = disp, carb = disp)`? But I am sure this is not what you are looking for?

Comment: `mutate_at(.tbl = mtcars, vars(mpg, carb), funs(.data$disp))`?

Comment: @Scarabee why is it `.data` and not `.tbl`? From the documentation it does not look like there is any argument `.data`. Also, could you tweak your solution to extract using the `[`?

Comment: @Scarabee The quoted rlang version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48891072/how-to-use-tidyeval-on-a-column-to-mutate/48892458#48892458

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
mutate_at(.tbl = mtcars, vars(mpg, carb), funs(.data$disp))
```

(or equivalently replace `.data$disp` with `.data[["disp"]]`).

---

Now to answer the question you asked in a comment:

> why is it `.data` and not `.tbl`?

Because `.data` is not the name of one of the function's arguments, but the pronoun from `rlang`. (See `?rlang::.data`)
So here `.data` refers to the data provided via the `.tbl` argument.

Note that you can **never** use an argument's name in the definition of another argument of the same function call. For instance consider the `+` function from base R. It has 2 arguments, namely `x` and `y` (as you can see in `?"+"`).

```
`+`(x = 2, y = 2)
# [1] 4
```

but

```
`+`(x = 2, y = x)
# Error: object 'x' not found
```